# Python3 requests.get ignoring part of my URL (BEAUTIFULSOUP + PYTHON WEBSCRAPING)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using requests.get like so:

```
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urllib3.disable_warnings()
cookies = {
    'PYPF': '3OyMLS2-xJlxKilWEOSvMQXAhyCgIhvAxYfbB8S_5lGBxxAS18Z7I8Q',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.227320333.1496647453',
    '_gat': '1',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.75815641.1496647453'
}
params = {
    'platform': 'xbox'
}
page = requests.get("http://www.rl-trades.com/#pf=xbox", headers={'Platform': 'Xbox'}, verify=False, cookies=cookies, params=params).text
page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

... etc.

But, from my results in testing, it seems requests.get is ignoring '/#pf=xbox' in 'http://www.rl-trades.com/#pf=xbox'.

Is this because I am having to set verify to false? What is going on here?

Comment: Everything works fine for me